# Show that 2x2 matrix (1 1 1 1) is symmetric positive semidefinite but is not symmetric positive definite

Tags: matrices

Should one calculate the eigenvalues and find that one of them is positive and the other is 0? Theorem says that if all eigenvalues are greater of equal to zero then matrix is spsd. But if all eigenvalues are not strictly greater than 0 then matrix is not spd.

Comment: Note that you can write the matrix as $(1,1)^T (1,1)$. From this you can find the eigenvectors fairly easily. Try $v=(1,1)^T$ to start and then pick something orthogonal.

Comment: you can use determinant characterization also. note that all one matrix has det zero

Comment: this is a rank one matrix and an eigenvector for the zero eigenvalue is $(1,-1)^\top$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what you should do.  In fact, in this case it is pretty easy to see what the eigenvectors are just by inspection:  $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = 2 \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @user220555  I actually recommend accepting the other answer.  It is well worth your while to understand the connection between our answers.  Also to understand how "completing the square" relates to finding the eigenvectors and values.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check the associated quadratic form is $(x+y)^2$. It's clearly positive, not definite.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working with complex numbers (so quadratic form proof is not that simple), as you said yourself a proof with eigenvalues is simplest.

The eigenvalues for matrix A (1 1 1 1)
are:

$$|\lambda I - A| = \det\begin{bmatrix} \lambda-1 & -1\\ -1 & \lambda-1\end{bmatrix} = (\lambda - 1)^2 - 1$$

The eigenvectors are therefore 0 and 2.